Is there a "stack trace" available after a MissingInputException [Snakemake]
The question
When there is a MissingInputException raised on a rule, we are provided with a list of the output files for the rule, the wildcards, and the "affected files" which are expected as input to the rule.
When debugging there are two main reasons why the affected files are not found:

the "affected files" list is correct, and there is a missing or malformatted rule to match those files, or the files are missing in the filesystem, or
the wildcards are unexpected and create an "affected files" list that has bad file names.

The first case is easy to debug, while the second is trickier.
Is there a way to see the "stack trace" of file name dependencies that produce the wildcards leading to a MissingInputException?

More background with an example
Imagine that we don't understand how rule matching works in Snakemake and we write the following in an attempt to produce this_is_an_input_file-summary.txt from tsv files called this_is.tsv an_input_file.tsv:
rule all:
  input: 'this_is_an_input_file-summary.txt'

rule A:
  input: '{prefix}.tsv'
  output: '{prefix}-summary.txt'

rule B:
  input: '{part1}.tsv', '{part2}.tsv'
  output: '{part1}_{part2}.tsv'

This will not work as expected of course, since rule B will match recursively and expect files this.tsv, is.tsv, an.tsv, input.tsv, and file.tsv.
The error will show up in rule B as a MissingInputException, and we can easily debug the situation because the workflow is so compact.
Now imagine that these rules are buried amongst hundreds of other rules with thousands of input files for rule all, and that there is a much more complex DAG leading to rule B.
The MissingInputException means that we have no way to produce the DAG.
Is there a way to print out the sequence of files and rules that lead to this exception, starting from the input file of rule all?

Maybe the --debug-dag option is what you are looking for?

@TroyComi:  That's close enough... thanks!

@TroyComi:  I could image a single trace leading from the error up the original filename, instead of a dump of every single rule and wildcard matched so far, but this is a start!

I've added an enhancement request on github: https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/issues/3063

@TroyComi had the answer but for the benefit of anyone else looking at this question (which is a common issue in Snakemake) here's the output of running --debug-dag on the sample workflow given in the question:
$ snakemake --debug-dag -n
Building DAG of jobs...
candidate job all
    wildcards: 
candidate job A
    wildcards: prefix=this_is_an_input_file
candidate job B
    wildcards: part1=this_is_an_input, part2=file
candidate job B
    wildcards: part1=this_is_an, part2=input
candidate job B
    wildcards: part1=this_is, part2=an
candidate job B
    wildcards: part1=this, part2=is
MissingInputException in rule B in file /home/tbooth2/workspace/snakemake_scratch/stack_overflow/debug_dag/Snakefile, line 8:
Missing input files for rule B:
    output: this_is.tsv
    wildcards: part1=this, part2=is
    affected files:
        this.tsv
        is.tsv


I agree that a stack trace would be a great enhancement.
